# PersistedGrants table is not getting written to?

Tags: identityserver4

The Identity Server 4 solution I'm working with is using the EF Identity DB.  I'm using the migration assembly to manage the client, API and Identity resource info. 
For some reason that I'm unaware of the persisted grant information is not being saved to the Persisted Grant table?  Please find below the start file and links to my log files from my latest test.

Identity Server Startup:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using AuthServer.Data;
using AuthServer.Models;
using AuthServer.Services;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace AuthServer
{
    public class Startup
    {
        #region "Startup"
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        #endregion

        #region "ConfigureServices"
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            // Add application services.
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

            services.AddMvc();

            string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

            // configure identity server with in-memory stores, keys, clients and scopes
            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
                // this adds the config data from DB (clients, resources)
                .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                            sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
                })
                // this adds the operational data from DB (codes, tokens, consents)
                .AddOperationalStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                            sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));

                    // this enables automatic token cleanup. this is optional.
                    options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
                    options.TokenCleanupInterval = 15; // interval in seconds. 15 seconds useful for debugging
                });

            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddGoogle("Google", options =>
                {
                    options.ClientId = "434483408261-55tc8n0cs4ff1fe21ea8df2o443v2iuc.apps.googleusercontent.com";
                    options.ClientSecret = "3gcoTrEDPPJ0ukn_aYYT6PWo";
                });
        }
        #endregion

        #region "Configure"
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            // app.UseAuthentication(); // not needed, since UseIdentityServer adds the authentication middleware
            app.UseIdentityServer();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Identity Server Log File:
https://github.com/gotnetdude/AuthServerWithAngularClient/blob/master/AuthServer/AuthServer_log.txt

Identity Server (AuthServer) source code:
https://github.com/gotnetdude/AuthServerWithAngularClient/tree/master/AuthServer

Thanks for the help... Paul

Answer (score 4):

Self-contained access tokens are not saved in the PersistedGrantStore.

As documented:

> Access tokens can come in two flavours - self-contained or reference.

http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/reference_tokens.html

> If authorization grants, consents, and tokens (refresh and reference)
>   are desired to be loaded from a EF-supported database (...), then the
>   operational store can be used.

http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/ef.html#operational-store-support-for-authorization-grants-consents-and-tokens-refresh-and-reference

Not very clear perhaps, but self-contained access tokens aren't mentioned here.

Comment: Good to know... There a lot to learn here for sure.  Sometimes trying figure translate the EF DB to the client, API and Identity resource setting is a bit confusing for me right now, but I'm learning.

Answer (score 2):

From what I saw - you are using an Angular client with Implicit flow (correct me if I'm wrong). The important here is the flow - `Implicit`.

The things that you see in the PesistedGrants table are most commonly `refresh tokens`. But - when using `Implicit` flow, `refresh token` **is not** issued.

This is most likely why you see all these lines in your log file.

However this should not bother you - SPA's have other approaches for refreshing their `access_token` - check [this](https://www.scottbrady91.com/OpenID-Connect/Silent-Refresh-Refreshing-Access-Tokens-when-using-the-Implicit-Flow), [this](https://damienbod.com/2017/06/02/implementing-a-silent-token-renew-in-angular-for-the-openid-connect-implicit-flow/) and [this](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js) (if you are not already using any of the approaches).

Hope that this helps

Comment: It make sense to me now that the refresh token option should not be used when using the Implicit grant type.  How does this affect the Operation Store EnableTokenCleanup and TokenCleanupInterval options?  Does it hurt anything if they're set when the grant type is Implicit?

Comment: If you are concerned about the access tokens - they expire, when they expire, and you cannot do anything about it. That's why it is recommended to keep them as short-lived as possible.

Comment: Sorry just saw the second part of your comment - no it doesn't hurt them. After all - you can have more than one client, with different grant types, and by this, the properties are useful. So keep them :)

Comment: Busy day, just read your previous comment.  Makes sense considering their can be multiple clients.  Definitely good to know...